# White space to the right of the screen

Tags: html, css

I need help with my site as it seems to have a rather large space of white to the right of my page. Everything fits into the page except if you were to scroll right you'd the part outside of my website, so all a want to do is ristrict the viewer from scrolling **right** or get rid of that space as I had done when you could scroll further down than what I built, The code is as shown below:

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#Header {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  width: 105%;
  height: 105px;
  margin: -1% -2.5%;
  position: relative;
}
#Title1 {
  width: 105%;
  height: 75px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  text-align: bottom;
  font-size: 250%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  margin: 0.4% 1%;
  position: fixed;
}
#nav_bar1 {
  font-size: 175%;
  margin: -60px 45%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  position: fixed;
}
#nav_bar1:hover {
  color: #18bc9c;
}
#nav_bar2 {
  font-size: 175%;
  margin: -60px 67%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  position: fixed;
}
#nav_bar2:hover {
  color: #18bc9c;
}
#nav_bar3 {
  font-size: 175%;
  margin: -60px 80%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  position: fixed;
}
#nav_bar3:hover {
  color: #18bc9c;
}
#Bootstrap {
  background-color: #18bc9c;
  width: 105%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: -2.5% -2.5%;
}
#Title2 {
  font-size: 320%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  margin: 0% 25%;
}
#img {
  margin: 4% 45%;
}
#Start_bootstrap {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0% 43%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
#Description {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1% 41%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
#Portfolio {
  font-size: 270%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin: 280px auto;
}
#about {
  background-color: #18bc9c;
  width: 105%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 795px -2.5%;
}
#about_title {
  margin: -1200px auto;
  font-size: 270%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#About_Me1 {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 1250px 30%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#Vertical_fix {
  width: 17.5%;
  margin: -161.5% 55%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#Vertical_fix2 {
  margin: -000px -300%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
  font-size: 270%;
}
#Contact_Header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 270%;
}
#Contact_Info {
  width: 50%;
  margin: -1400px 25%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.center {
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 102.5%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #18bc9c;
  margin: -110% -0.85%;
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Header">
    <div id="Title1">.@BOOTSTRAP</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right" id="nav_bar1">EXPERIENCE</div>
  <div class="right" id="nav_bar2">ABOUT</div>
  <div class="right" id="nav_bar3">CONTACT</div>

  <div id="Bootstrap">
    <img src="profile.png" class="center" id="img">
    <h1 id="Start_bootstrap">START BOOTSTRAP</h1>
    <p id="Description">Web Developer - Graphic Artist - User Experience Designer</p>



    <div class="center" id="Portfolio">
      <p>My Experiences are..</p>
      <img src="C:\Users\ben\Pictures\inknpixel.png">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="about">
  </div>

  <div class="center" id="about_title">A bit more...</div>

  <p id="About_Me1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec bibendum arcu in massa dapibus, in vehicula mauris consequat. Suspendisse ac mauris quis lorem commodo scelerisque. Duis in commodo nisl, vel volutpat ipsum. Pellentesque placerat lobortis
    faucibus. Nulla interdum quam a risus, aliquam porta. Mauris pulvinar, ante a vulputate rutrum, lorem diam blandit est, non porta quam enim eu lectus. Maecenas nulla mi, feugiat vitae tortor a, fringilla aliquam nunc. Vestibulum ornare dignissim est
    ut porta. Etiam placerat aliquam ipsum nec gravida. Fusce quis rhoncus dui. Praesent vehicula mollis tellus.</p>

  <p id="Vertical_fix">aliquam</p>
  </div>





  <div class="center" id="Contact_Info">
    <p style="color: #2c3e50; font-size: 270%; font-family: Helvetica; text-align: 60%">You can find me at...</p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec bibendum feugiat vitae tortor a, fringilla aliquam nunc. Vestibulum ornare dignissim est ut porta. Etiam placerat aliquam lectus. Maecenas nulla mi, feugiat vitae tortor a, fringilla aliquam
      nunc. Vestibulum ornare dignissim est ut porta. Etiam placerat aliquam ipsum nec gravida. Fusce quis rhoncus dui. Praesent vehicula mollis tellus placerat aliquam ipsum nec gravida. Fusce quis rhoncus dui. Praesent vehicula mollis tellus
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because you are using margin like `-60px 67%;` which says 67% space to the right...

Comment: yes, your margins aren't going to help you, and widths over 100% are going to contribute to the white space you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

```css
#Start_bootstrap {
    margin: 0% 43%;
    width: 100%;
}
#Description {
    margin: 1% 41%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Basically, you set their width tp 100% of their parent, and you push them a lot to the right.

If you want to center, better use

```css
#Start_bootstrap, #Description {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#Header {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  width: 105%;
  height: 105px;
  margin: -1% -2.5%;
  position: relative;
}
#Title1 {
  width: 105%;
  height: 75px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  text-align: bottom;
  font-size: 250%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  margin: 0.4% 1%;
  position: fixed;
}
#nav_bar1 {
  font-size: 175%;
  margin: -60px 45%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  position: fixed;
}
#nav_bar1:hover {
  color: #18bc9c;
}
#nav_bar2 {
  font-size: 175%;
  margin: -60px 67%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  position: fixed;
}
#nav_bar2:hover {
  color: #18bc9c;
}
#nav_bar3 {
  font-size: 175%;
  margin: -60px 80%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  position: fixed;
}
#nav_bar3:hover {
  color: #18bc9c;
}
#Bootstrap {
  background-color: #18bc9c;
  width: 105%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: -2.5% -2.5%;
}
#Title2 {
  font-size: 320%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  margin: 0% 25%;
}
#img {
  margin: 4% 45%;
}
#Start_bootstrap, #Description {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
#Portfolio {
  font-size: 270%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin: 280px auto;
}
#about {
  background-color: #18bc9c;
  width: 105%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 795px -2.5%;
}
#about_title {
  margin: -1200px auto;
  font-size: 270%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#About_Me1 {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 1250px 30%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#Vertical_fix {
  width: 17.5%;
  margin: -161.5% 55%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#Vertical_fix2 {
  margin: -000px -300%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
  font-size: 270%;
}
#Contact_Header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 270%;
}
#Contact_Info {
  width: 50%;
  margin: -1400px 25%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #2c3e50;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.center {
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 102.5%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #18bc9c;
  margin: -110% -0.85%;
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Header">
    <div id="Title1">.@BOOTSTRAP</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right" id="nav_bar1">EXPERIENCE</div>
  <div class="right" id="nav_bar2">ABOUT</div>
  <div class="right" id="nav_bar3">CONTACT</div>

  <div id="Bootstrap">
    <img src="profile.png" class="center" id="img">
    <h1 id="Start_bootstrap">START BOOTSTRAP</h1>
    <p id="Description">Web Developer - Graphic Artist - User Experience Designer</p>



    <div class="center" id="Portfolio">
      <p>My Experiences are..</p>
      <img src="C:\Users\ben\Pictures\inknpixel.png">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="about">
  </div>

  <div class="center" id="about_title">A bit more...</div>

  <p id="About_Me1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec bibendum arcu in massa dapibus, in vehicula mauris consequat. Suspendisse ac mauris quis lorem commodo scelerisque. Duis in commodo nisl, vel volutpat ipsum. Pellentesque placerat lobortis
    faucibus. Nulla interdum quam a risus, aliquam porta. Mauris pulvinar, ante a vulputate rutrum, lorem diam blandit est, non porta quam enim eu lectus. Maecenas nulla mi, feugiat vitae tortor a, fringilla aliquam nunc. Vestibulum ornare dignissim est
    ut porta. Etiam placerat aliquam ipsum nec gravida. Fusce quis rhoncus dui. Praesent vehicula mollis tellus.</p>

  <p id="Vertical_fix">aliquam</p>
  </div>





  <div class="center" id="Contact_Info">
    <p style="color: #2c3e50; font-size: 270%; font-family: Helvetica; text-align: 60%">You can find me at...</p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec bibendum feugiat vitae tortor a, fringilla aliquam nunc. Vestibulum ornare dignissim est ut porta. Etiam placerat aliquam lectus. Maecenas nulla mi, feugiat vitae tortor a, fringilla aliquam
      nunc. Vestibulum ornare dignissim est ut porta. Etiam placerat aliquam ipsum nec gravida. Fusce quis rhoncus dui. Praesent vehicula mollis tellus placerat aliquam ipsum nec gravida. Fusce quis rhoncus dui. Praesent vehicula mollis tellus
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```