# What exactly is causing the width to be bigger than it should on my webpage?

Tags: html, css

I'm really not sure what is happening here. I've commented out areas of code that I suspected it would be, made sure it wasn't a glitch, there's something I'm obviously not seeing here. Hope one of you web design **experts** can help me here.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}
```

I've tried setting overflow-x to hidden which fixes it, the problem is that when I do that the overflow-y seems to be automatically set to auto instead of visible and doesn't change when I set it manually to visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/jg10vzcx/

Comment: possible duplicate of [White space to the right of the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284224/white-space-to-the-right-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is the `.sub-text` element. It is a block level paragraph element with a default width of `100%`. You are positioning it with `left: calc(50% - 15vw)` in order to center it. In doing so, it is extending past the viewport (because it has a width of `100%`) and it is creating a horizontal scrollbar.

You can remove the `left` positioning and simply add `text-align: center` to the element in order to center it.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/md6zx9r8/)

```
.sub-text {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    /* left: calc(50% - 15vw); */
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1vw black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: yep.. what he said... remove your P tag to quickly test..
When i come across these issues, i simply remove chunks until it disappears. that way you can narrow it down to a single element in the end.

Comment: 15 years plus with web dev and its still easy to over look the smallest thing like a missing semicolon

Comment: Thanks! I find it kinda weird that just that element was doing that, but I guess that's what happens when you use a new method without much knowledge of it.